# Return only capitalised names from a SQL query

Tags: postgresql

I have a table storing first names and surnames; some may be stored with capitalisation. Is there a query I could use to return only those rows with capitalisation?

For instance, if I have the following entries:

```
firstname  | surname
-----------+-----------
Bob        | Jones
john       | bobbins
```

I'd only expect to be returned the record for "Bob Jones".

I'm sure it's not a difficult thing to do, but I haven't been able to find any examples anywhere.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  What does "return only those rows with capitalisation" really mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare the value with the value where the first character is upper-case:

```
select *
from the_table
where firstname = initcap(firstname)
  and surname = initcap(surname);
```

The function `initcap()` converts the first letter of each word to upper case and the rest to lower case.

Comment: `O'Brian`s are so lucky, but poor `MacLeod`s though.

Comment: @pozs: very true :)